# CSS Filter on Retina Display: Fuzzy Images

Tags: css, filter, css-transitions, retina-display

When you apply a -webkit-filter and a -webkit-transition to an Image and change the filter on hover, the image transition does well, but then the image gets really fuzzy.

**Note:** This only happens on *Retina-Displays* — no problem at all with 'normal' ppi-displays, but fuzzy on for example a new MacBook Pro with Retina Display.

My CSS (without vendor-prefixes):

```
img {filter:grayscale(1);filter:saturate(0%);transition:2s ease;width:200px;height:200px}
img:hover {filter:grayscale(0)}​
```

Note: to see the effect/bug, I've set the transition-duration to 2 Seconds

Check out my Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dya2t/7/

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** If I set the :hover-state to filter:none its sharp! :-) BUT of course the transition does not work anymore :-/
As soon as there is a filter on an image (even if the value is 0 or 0%), the image gets fuzzy on retina displays (with or without transitions … its just blurry, all the time). I guess this is a Filter-Bug.

---

This is a known Bug in WebKit https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93471

Comment: you can chain filters like this: 'filter: grayscale(0.5) blur(1px) saturate(2);' etc.. : http://jsfiddle.net/meo/dya2t/9/ but i don't know if this fixes your problem i don't have a retina screen

Comment: @meo: chaining filters unfortunately aren't helping, thx anyway

Comment: In your fiddle the saturation filter simply overrides the grayscale one. You should get rid of the saturation one. It won't solve the sharpness issue, but at least your filter will work :)

Comment: I already filed a bug for this issue: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93471

Comment: @heartcode: I discovered that adding saturation filter does fix the flashing-context bug, therefore I added this filter.

Comment: When I try the demo with the added saturation filter, it simply can't see the transition. It just 0-1 with no transition in 2s, which is weird.

Comment: I don't see any transition here... Note that I'm using Chrome...

Answer (score 39):

I managed to get around this issue by applying to the img tag:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78qbn/3/

Comment: I can confirm this workaround works perfectly. I belive this is the correct answer, as the question was "how can I fix this", not "what is the problem here" :)

Comment: How did you figure this out? This is awesome.

Comment: Another random safari CSS glitch  Thanks for figuring it out @Jean-Michel!

Answer (score 4):

Child elements with -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; will resolve this.

http://codepen.io/amboy00/pen/Bxbrd

Comment: This one did the trick for me where ```-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)``` didn't, thanks!

Comment: `-webkit-transform` worked for me, but it clipped the edge of the image; this also worked but with no clipping. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Joined stackoverflow to let others know since I had to find this out myself:
this bug also manifests (but differently) when trying to print images in chrome. They turn **super pixelated**!

If you throw a `-webkit-filter` onto a PNG in chrome regardless of printer or print settings, it prints the image/s at the right size, but downsampled to under 70 dpi. It's visible in the print preview too.

`-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` fixed it.

Meatspace repro: [prints of same stack of PNGs with & without fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aGn3.jpg)